# logcat error "table has no column named..."

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

i have to develop a fall detector app and i decide to create a database to save information about it. but when the app has to write into database there's an error appearing on logcat. here is the logcat error

```
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724): Error inserting NCadute=0 DataInizio=2015/5/12 Durata=0:0:0 OraInizio=6:14:30 Nome=gshsgsusg
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Sessione has no column named NCadute: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Sessione(NCadute, DataInizio, Durata, OraInizio, Nome) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute.MyDBManager.addSessione(MyDBManager.java:37)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute.Third$1.onClick(Third.java:47)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-12 06:14:33.892: E/Database(2724):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is code java of sqliteopenhelper

```
package it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "progettoDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_SESSIONE = "Sessione";
public static final String TABLE_CADUTA="Caduta";   

public static final String COL_IDS = "_id";
public static final String COL_NOME = "Nome";
public static final String COL_DATA = "DataInizio";
public static final String COL_ORA="OraInizio";
public static final String COL_DURATA = "Durata";
public static final String COL_NCADUTE = "NCadute";

public static final String COL_IDC="_id";
public static final String COL_DATAC = "DataCaduta";
public static final String COL_ORAC = "OraCaduta";
public static final String COL_LAT = "Latitudine";
public static final String COL_LON = "Longitudine";
public static final String COL_SESS = "NSessione"; 

public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}   
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_SESSIONE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_SESSIONE + "("
                + COL_IDS + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + COL_NOME  + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + COL_DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + COL_ORA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
                + COL_DURATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + COL_NCADUTE + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + ");";     
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SESSIONE_TABLE);

    /*String CREATE_CADUTA_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_CADUTA + "("
                + COL_IDC + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_DATAC 
                + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COL_ORAC + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                        + COL_LAT + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COL_LON + "TEXT         NOT NULL," 
    + COL_SESS + "TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CADUTA_TABLE);*/
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SESSIONE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CADUTA);
        onCreate(db);
}   

}
```

this is the code java where i manage database(MyDBManager.java)

```
package it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;

public class MyDBManager{

private MyDBHelper dbhelper;

public MyDBManager(Context ctx){

    dbhelper=new MyDBHelper(ctx);
    //SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close(){

dbhelper.close();   

}


public void addSessione(String nome, String data, String ora, String durata ,int ncadute){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_NOME, nome);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_DATA, data);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_ORA, ora);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_DURATA, durata);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_NCADUTE, ncadute);                        

    db.insert(MyDBHelper.TABLE_SESSIONE, null, cv);
}

public void addCaduta(String data, String ora, String lat, String lon, String sessione){

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_DATAC, data);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_ORAC, ora);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_LAT, lat);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_LON, lon);
    cv.put(MyDBHelper.COL_SESS, sessione);

    db.insert(MyDBHelper.TABLE_CADUTA, null, cv);
}

public boolean deleteSessione(int id){
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
try{
    if(db.delete(MyDBHelper.TABLE_SESSIONE, MyDBHelper.COL_IDS + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)})> 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
catch(SQLiteException sqle){
    return false;
}   
}

public boolean renameSessione(String newName, int id)
{
SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
String RENAME_SESSIONE = "UPDATE" + MyDBHelper.TABLE_SESSIONE + "SET"    + MyDBHelper.COL_NOME + "=" 
                        + newName + "WHERE"+ MyDBHelper.COL_IDS + "= ?" + id + "";
db.execSQL(RENAME_SESSIONE);
return true;
}

public Cursor selectSessione(){
Cursor crs=null;
 try
 {
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    crs=db.query(MyDBHelper.TABLE_SESSIONE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);        
 }
 catch(SQLiteException sqle)
 {
   return null;
   }     
 return crs;
 }

 public Cursor selectCaduta()
 {
 Cursor crs=null;
 try
 {
     SQLiteDatabase db=dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
     crs=db.query(MyDBHelper.TABLE_CADUTA, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

 }
 catch(SQLiteException sqle)
 {
     return null;
 }     
 return crs;     
 }

}
```

this is the mainactivity java where i open db and then close it

```
package it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {   

MyDBManager db= new MyDBManager(this);  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    List<Dati> list = new LinkedList<Dati>();

    Cursor crs=db.selectSessione();         
    if(crs.moveToFirst()){
        String strData =    crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("DataInizio"));
        String[] dataf=strData.split("/");
        int day=Integer.parseInt(dataf[0]);  
        int month=Integer.parseInt(dataf[1]);  
        int year=Integer.parseInt(dataf[2]);

        String strTime = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("OraInizio"));
        String[] oraf=strTime.split(":");
        int hour=Integer.parseInt(oraf[0]);  
        int minutes=Integer.parseInt(oraf[1]);  
        int seconds=Integer.parseInt(oraf[2]); 
        do{
            list.add(new Dati(crs.getString(0),day, month, year,hour, minutes, seconds));
        }while(crs.moveToNext());//fine while
    }
    else{
        list.add(new Dati());
    }
    crs.close();

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_items, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id){
        //Dati value = (Dati)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent UI2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
        startActivity(UI2);
        }
    });        
    //db.close();

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (db != null) 
    {
        db.close();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem meIt1 = menu.add(0, R.id.nuovaSessione, 1, "Nuova Sessione");
    MenuItem meIt2 = menu.add(0, R.id.delete, 2, "Elimina");
    MenuItem meIt3 = menu.add(0, R.id.rinomina, 3, "Rinomina");
    MenuItem meIt4 = menu.add(0, R.id.preferenze, 4, "Preferenze");
    meIt1.setIntent(new Intent(this, Third.class));
    meIt4.setIntent(new Intent(this, Fifth.class));
    meIt3.setIntent(new Intent(this, Sixth.class));
    return true;
} 

}
```

and at least this is the code java where i insert a raw in database(Third.java)

```
package it.unipd.dei.rilevatoredicadute;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Third extends ActionBarActivity {

Dati da = new Dati();
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);


    final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.insTesto);      

    final ImageButton playBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);
    final ImageButton pauseBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    final ImageButton stopBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //boolean play=true;
            //if(play){
            playBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   

            da.setData(cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR), cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE));
            String data = da.getData();

            da.setHour(cal.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE), cal.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND));
            String ora = da.getHour();

            MyDBManager db = new MyDBManager(getApplicationContext());
            db.addSessione(et.getText().toString(), data, ora, "0:0:0", 0);
            db.close();
            /*play=false;
            }
            else{
                playBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pauseBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }*/
             }          
    });
}

/*@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/
}
```

i follow suggest for changing database version and unistalling and re-installing app on device(archos) but logcat gave me the same problem. Somebody can help me?
PS Sorry for my very bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are created as first time to use. If you add another table,this table can not be created because oncreate methot creates table as first time to use.
uprage db version and use onUprage override method to delete tables and call oncreate method